# Correct syntax for top x rows MongoDB Strict in Azure Data Factory pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm using a pipeline to copy data from CosmoDB to a Azure Data Lake, this within a Data Factory.
I'm using the MongoDB API instead of the SQL.

There is a field in which we can enter a Filter expression, in the manuals there is specified that we have to use them in Strict mode instead Shell mode.

As I'm totally new to Cosmo/Mongo I need some help for retrieving the top x records.

As a Sample, this filter works `{"TrainKey.TrainNumber" : {$eq: 11332 }}`.

But now I tried several option with `{$limit: 100}` or `{limit(100)}`, but none of them works.

Could anybody point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the strict mode in the [mongo db manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/),still no luck as same as you.However, you could configure `cursorMethods.limit`([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-mongodb#copy-activity-properties)) to implement `$limit` feature.

[image]

I tested it on my side and it works.

[image]